# Scanning directory using path which contains spaces

Tags: php, ajax, кодировка

Что нужно сделать, чтобы функция scandir заработала с путями в которых есть пробелы

1. Я пробовал использовать функцию **urlencode**
2. Пробовал просто передавать путь без форматирования
3. Путь выглядит как "./" или "./Folder" или же "./Folder/New Folder". Первый и второй вариант работает отлично, чего не могу сказать о третьем.

   ```
   //getfiles.php
   if(isset($_POST['path']))
       $cur_dir.='/'.$_POST['path'];

   try
   {
      $raw_files = scandir(urlencode($cur_dir));
      if(count($raw_files) > 2)
      {
          $files = array_slice($raw_files,2);
          //other part of code
   ```

   JS

   ```
   var cur_dir = "uploads/New folder";
       getFiles();
       function getFiles()
       {
               $.ajax({
               data: {'path':cur_dir},
               url:"getfiles.php",
               type:"POST",
               success:function(data)
                   {
                       alert(data);
                   }
               });
       }
   ```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть что в $raw_files из строки
   ` $raw_files = scandir(urlencode($cur_dir));`